# ListView doesn't update unless screen orientation is changed

Tags: java, android, listview, android-actionbar, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to make an app which displays a list of books using google book's API. I'm able to populate the list items, but unless the screen orientation is changed the list views do not show up.

How can I update the list views as soon the search button is clicked?

[Here is the entire project on github.](https://github.com/henokali1/Books)

Comment: Please do not link all your code to Github and expect someone to go there.  A Q&A should live without relying on external sources.  Please make an [edit] with the code you're having an issue with.  I would encourage you to read [ask], too.

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncTask is asynchronous, so the `extractBooks` method is called before the request is done.

You should call this method in `doInBackground` and binds data in list in the `onPostExecute` method.